# Does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate make changes in DB schema?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

On production environment I am using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate but I found new columns are added in my production DB automatically.

I have done a small POC with dummy application it is not adding a column on my local system.

Can anyone help me understand what could be the issue with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` property.

Any help is appreciated.

PFA I visited the documentation but did not get enough details:
[image]

Documentation URL : 
[enter link description here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

Comment: If anything called "validate" makes changes then you should report it, since that is what "update" is for.

Comment: You mention a spring configuration that it uses to pass through to Hibernate but you don't mention what columns or provide any example of the changes which you see happening?  What's the say the columns you're seeing added aren't related to some spring-data-jpa specific implementation which has nothing to do with Hibernate.  More details would be helpful imo.

Answer (score 4):

Yes in production env, the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` are being passed from external .properties file.

Now I am pretty sure that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` never update the DB schema.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`validate` should not change your database schema.

If it does you should file an issue, although I doubt that this is what is really happening.

What I consider more likely that either

- you have multiple configurations and a different one then the one you are looking at is getting picked up.
- Something completely different is your database schema.

In order to debug this situation do the following:

1. make sure you can reproduce the schema changing behavior, e.g. by adding and removing an entity.
2. step by step remove everything from the project that isn't necessary for reproducing the behavior. This should leave you with a tiny project: a build file, an entity, a class representing your application to start everything up, maybe one or two configuration files.

If you actually succeed with step 2 while still reproducing the schema changing behavior update your question or directly file a bug.

If (what I'm currently expecting) at some point during step 2 the weird behavior goes away you found your culprint.

If it isn't obvious: you want to do all this using version control so you can undo/redo/review steps.